# Webhook event payloads and whether to batch them and/or put in background process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webhooks

I'm currently processing event payloads from a webhook via background processing (such as delayedjobs) even though the processing is very minimal. Is this the right way to go about it?

Also, what happens if there are many payload events coming in? Is it smarter to batch the events to process multiple payloads at a time? If so, would love a few pointers on how to do it on a rails/heroku server.